# Highcharts - Sankey chart - How to display some series dataLabels name into icon or some different name

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a simple sankey charts of highcharts. I am plotting it using a sample data.Every thing is working fine but I need to display some dataLabels as a different name.For Example in my data there is Brazil1 and Canada1, So where ever its contains Brazil1 and Canada1, I need to display Brazil and Canada using some condition. Here I can change it manually but my link will not work as its working.It won't point to each other.Here is my code below

### HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

### SCRIPT

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Sankey Diagram'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueDescriptionFormat: '{index}. {point.from} to {point.to}, {point.weight}.'
        }
    },

        exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
       series: [{
         dataLabels: {
           style: {
             fontSize: "6px",
             fontWeight: "normal"
           }
         }
       }]
       }
      },
    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['Brazil', 'Brazil1', 5],
            ['Brazil', 'France', 1],
            ['Brazil', 'Spain', 1],
            ['Brazil', 'England', 1],
            ['Canada', 'Canada1', 1],
            ['Canada', 'France', 5],
            ['Canada', 'England', 1],

        ],
         dataLabels: {
         allowOverlap: true,
           style: {
             fontSize: "15px",
             fontWeight: "normal"
           }
         },
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'Sankey demo series'
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize how the labels are formatted with the following methods:

- Tooltips: [tooltip.pointFormatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.tooltip.pointFormatter)
- Data labels on nodes: [dataLabels.nodeFormatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.dataLabels.nodeFormatter)
- Data labels on arrows: [dataLabels.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.dataLabels.formatter)

Note that you'll need to provide a translation table to map your unwanted country name to the one you want. For example:

```
countries = {
  Brazil1: 'Wanted Brazil1 name', 
  Canada1: 'Wanted Canada1 name', 
};
```

**Tooltips**

In that formatter, the data point `{ from, to, weight }` can be accessed via `this`, so we can write:

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormatter: function() {
    console.log('tooltip formatter', this);
    point = this;
    from = countries[point.from] || point.from;
    to = countries[point.to] || point.to;
    weight = point.weight
    return from + ' → ' + to + ': ' + weight;
  },
},
```

**Labels on nodes**

In that formatter, the country can be accessed via `this.key`, so we can write:

```
dataLabels: {
  nodeFormatter: function() {
    console.log('node formatter', this);
    return countries[this.key] || this.key;
  },
},
```

**Labels on arrows**

In that formatter, the data point `{ from, to, weight }` can be accessed via `this.point`, so we can write:

```
dataLabels: {
  formatter: function() {
    console.log('formatter', this);
    point = this.point;
    from = countries[point.from] || point.from;
    to = countries[point.to] || point.to;
    weight = point.weight
    return from + ' → ' + to + ': ' + weight;
  },
},
```

You can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/Metoule/q80t36ay/1/